# Canvas - background image instead transparent background under chroma image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

#### I need to replace green background with my own background image with (x,y positioning).

At this moment I just removed green background from https://s14.postimg.org/x9hmont5d/image.jpg with Seriously.js library.

https://jsfiddle.net/0xz7cfkL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style>
      #canvas {
        border: 2px solid #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="800" id="canvas" height="600"></canvas>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/brianchirls/Seriously.js@r2015-09-08/seriously.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/brianchirls/Seriously.js@r2015-09-08/effects/seriously.chroma.js"></script>
    <script>
      let image = new Image();
      image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
      image.src = 'https://s14.postimg.org/x9hmont5d/image.jpg';

      let seriously = new Seriously();
      let canvas = seriously.target('#canvas');

      let chroma = seriously.effect('chroma');
      chroma.source = seriously.source(image);

      canvas.source = chroma;

      seriously.go();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the SeriouslyJS library, the background image can be added using the blend-plugin. You need to include this next to the chroma script-tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/brianchirls/Seriously.js@r2015-09-08/effects/seriously.blend.js"></script>
```

In the main script, you could add a background image in the same fashion as the first:

```
let bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
bgImage.src = 'https://picsum.photos/800/600?random';
```

Finally, replace "canvas.source":

```
let blend = seriously.effect('blend');
blend.top = chroma;
blend.bottom = seriously.source(bgImage);  

canvas.source = blend;
```

I hope I didn't miss something. You can check out and run the whole script in the snippet:

```js
let image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
image.src = 'https://s14.postimg.org/x9hmont5d/image.jpg';
let bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
bgImage.src = 'https://picsum.photos/800/600?random';

let seriously = new Seriously();
let canvas = seriously.target('#canvas');

let chroma = seriously.effect('chroma');
chroma.source = seriously.source(image);

let blend = seriously.effect('blend');
blend.top = chroma;
blend.bottom = seriously.source(bgImage);

canvas.source = blend;

seriously.go();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <style>
    #canvas {
      border: 2px solid #000;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas width="800" id="canvas" height="600"></canvas>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/brianchirls/Seriously.js@r2015-09-08/seriously.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/brianchirls/Seriously.js@r2015-09-08/effects/seriously.chroma.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/brianchirls/Seriously.js@r2015-09-08/effects/seriously.blend.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

An alternative solution could use HTML and CSS to position an image at a z-index behind the canvas. (I would use this if the first one won't work)

```js
let image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
image.src = 'https://s14.postimg.org/x9hmont5d/image.jpg';

let seriously = new Seriously();
let canvas = seriously.target('#canvas');

let chroma = seriously.effect('chroma');
chroma.source = seriously.source(image);

canvas.source = chroma;

seriously.go();
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#myBg {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#canvas {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600?random" id="myBg" />
    <canvas width="800" id="canvas" height="600"></canvas>

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/brianchirls/Seriously.js@r2015-09-08/seriously.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/brianchirls/Seriously.js@r2015-09-08/effects/seriously.chroma.js"></script>
  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice! But how can I position image at bottom or top? (x, y) padding etc.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that. I solved it now. First, include `seriously.layers.js`. Then finish the blend code with `     let transform = seriously.transform('2d');
      transform.translateX = canvas.width / 2;
      transform.translateY = canvas.height / 4;
      transform.source = seriously.source(bgImage);
      
      let layers = seriously.effect('layers', {count: 2});
      layers.source0 = transform;
      layers.source1 = chroma;
      canvas.source = layers;` Transform is built-in with core and need not be included.

Comment: Should you go with the alternative solution, you just need to add to the CSS rule #myBg something like `left: 400px; bottom: -150px;`

Comment: I can not do this via CSS cause than I need to export the result as JPEG.